# How to create this database using Object Oriented Modelling

Tags: java

**Users**

There are two types of users in the system for the purpose of access control: administrators and regular users.

Anyone can register and becomes a regular user in the system. During registration, a user must provide the following information:

First and last name
Position: Student, Faculty, or Staff
Organizational unit: this could be a college, a department, a division, an office (e.g. Office of Undergraduate Studies), or undeclared for students.
Username and password
Email
Optional information provided by a user during registration include:

Title: for example, "Director of LSAMP" or "President of ACM Student Chapter"
Program Affiliations, e.g. LSAMP, LSAMP-BD, MBRS-RISE, MARC-U*STAR, Bridges to the Future, ACS-Project Seed, NSF-CREST,  FYrE@ECST, BOOST, MEP, CAPS, and so on.

**Events**

Any user can submit events to be posted on the web portal. An event must be reviewed and approved by an administrator before it is posted, except that if a user is designated as an Event Organizer, the events submitted by the user can be posted directly.

An event has a name, a description, a location, a start time and an end time. An event may have tags, which are keywords describing event type, content, affiliations, and so on. For example, a workshop on robotics hosted by the ACM Student Chapter can be tagged with "Robotics", "ACM", "Computer Science".

The system must keep track of who attended an event (we assume there will be a check-in mechanism).

Comment: That's a nice description, but can you also describe your question as you described your system?

Comment: I want to use JPA annotations to map the relational scheme

Comment: I guess you need 2 tables first for users(1 column should be isAdmin with default value false for registering) and second for events(1 column should be isAproved default value false until administrator accepts except special ocassion witch you program). I hope this helped you

Answer (score 0):

```
//Model for user class
@Entity
public class User{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private String id;

@Column
@NotNull
private String userType;  //can be regular user or admin

@Column
@NotNull
private String firstName;

@Column
@NotNull
private String lastName;

@Column
@NotNull
private String position;

@Column
@NotNull
private String organizationalUnit;

@Column
@NotNull
private String userName;

@Column
@NotNull
private String password;

@Column
@NotNull
private String email;

@Column
private String title;

@Column
private String programAffiliations;

//create the getters and setters
}

//Model for event
@Entity
public class Event{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private String id;

@Column
@NotNull
private String description;  

@Column
@NotNull
private String location;

@Column
@NotNull
private long startTime;

@Column
@NotNull
private long endTime;

@Column
private String eventType;

@Column
private String content;

@Column
private String affiliation;

//create the getters and setters
}
```

You can track the people who created an event and who attended an event by storing the user Id and event Id in a separate tables as required by creating a mapping. Do mappings between users and events as required.